# Using a wildcard to delegate tasks to a server in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Very new to Ansible, so bear with me if I explain things poorly.

We have a set of servers in a windows environment that follow the following syntax for their naming conventions.

```
ServerXydv1
ServerXydv2
ServerYzdv1
ServerYzdv2
ServerXyqa1
ServerXyqa2
ServerYzqa1
ServerYzqa2
ServerXy1
ServerXy2
ServerYz1
ServerYz2
```

The host.ini has each of these servers grouped by both their environment (dv, qa, pr) and by their function (Xy, Yz)
for example:

```
[dev]
ServerXydv1
ServerXydv2
ServerYzdv1
ServerYzdv2

[Xy]
ServerXydv1
ServerXydv2
ServerXyqa1
ServerXyqa2
ServerXy1
ServerXy2
```

I would like to have effectively 2 yaml that can dynamically select what servers to use.

My main yaml file:

```
- name : "Start"
  hosts: "{{ host_names }}"
  vars:
   ansible_port: 5555
   ansible_connection: winrm
   ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
   ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
  tasks:
   - name: Import Xy Hello
     import_tasks:
     file: "XyHello.yaml"
     when: inventory_hostname in groups\["Xy"\]
```

XHello.yaml

```
- name: XES1 Say Hello
  win_shell: echo "Say Hello Xy1"
  delegate_to: ServerX*1
- name: XES2 Say Hello
  win_shell: echo "Say Hello Xy2"
  delegate_to: ServerX*2
```

For this example assume host_names = dev
It connects to the servers, skips the appropriate servers for the conditional, imports the tasks, but does not recognize the wildcard * in the delegate_to line.
In the final product the line will run different tasks depending on being a 1 server or a 2 server.

What am I missing? How can I get it to run the right task on the right server but keep the playbook environment agnostic?

Answer (score 1):

Put all hosts into a single file. For example,

```ini
shell> cat inventory/01-hosts 
ServerXydv1
ServerXydv2
ServerYzdv1
ServerYzdv2
ServerXyqa1
ServerXyqa2
ServerYzqa1
ServerYzqa2
ServerXy1
ServerXy2
ServerYz1
ServerYz2
```

Use the inventory plugin *ansible.builtin.constructed* to create groups. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t inventory ansible.builtin.constructed
```

For example,

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/02-constructed.yml 
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
groups:
  dv: inventory_hostname[8:10] == 'dv'
  qa: inventory_hostname[8:10] == 'qa'
  xy: inventory_hostname[6:8] == 'Xy'
  yz: inventory_hostname[6:8] == 'Yz'
  x1: inventory_hostname[6] == 'X' and inventory_hostname[-1] == '1'
  x2: inventory_hostname[6] == 'X' and inventory_hostname[-1] == '2'
  y1: inventory_hostname[6] == 'Y' and inventory_hostname[-1] == '1'
  y2: inventory_hostname[6] == 'Y' and inventory_hostname[-1] == '2'
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    dv:
      hosts:
        ServerXydv1: {}
        ServerXydv2: {}
        ServerYzdv1: {}
        ServerYzdv2: {}
    qa:
      hosts:
        ServerXyqa1: {}
        ServerXyqa2: {}
        ServerYzqa1: {}
        ServerYzqa2: {}
    ungrouped: {}
    x1:
      hosts:
        ServerXy1: {}
        ServerXydv1: {}
        ServerXyqa1: {}
    x2:
      hosts:
        ServerXy2: {}
        ServerXydv2: {}
        ServerXyqa2: {}
    xy:
      hosts:
        ServerXy1: {}
        ServerXy2: {}
        ServerXydv1: {}
        ServerXydv2: {}
        ServerXyqa1: {}
        ServerXyqa2: {}
    y1:
      hosts:
        ServerYz1: {}
        ServerYzdv1: {}
        ServerYzqa1: {}
    y2:
      hosts:
        ServerYz2: {}
        ServerYzdv2: {}
        ServerYzqa2: {}
    yz:
      hosts:
        ServerYz1: {}
        ServerYz2: {}
        ServerYzdv1: {}
        ServerYzdv2: {}
        ServerYzqa1: {}
        ServerYzqa2: {}
```

Use the groups in a playbook. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: Xy hello
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.xy
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory pb.yml 

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************
ok: [ServerXydv1] => 
  msg: Xy hello
ok: [ServerXydv2] => 
  msg: Xy hello
skipping: [ServerYzdv1]
skipping: [ServerYzdv2]
ok: [ServerXyqa1] => 
  msg: Xy hello
ok: [ServerXyqa2] => 
  msg: Xy hello
ok: [ServerXy1] => 
  msg: Xy hello
ok: [ServerXy2] => 
  msg: Xy hello
skipping: [ServerYzqa1]
skipping: [ServerYzqa2]
skipping: [ServerYz1]
skipping: [ServerYz2]
  ...
```

Optionally, you can use *regex*. The below configuration gives the same results

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/02-constructed.yml
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
groups:
  dv: inventory_hostname is regex 'Server.*dv.*'
  qa: inventory_hostname is regex 'Server.*qa.*'
  xy: inventory_hostname is regex 'Server.*Xy.*'
  yz: inventory_hostname is regex 'Server.*Yz.*'
  x1: inventory_hostname is regex 'ServerX.*1'
  x2: inventory_hostname is regex 'ServerX.*2'
  y1: inventory_hostname is regex 'ServerY.*1'
  y2: inventory_hostname is regex 'ServerY.*2'
```